# How to use SQL Wildcard in PreparedStatement with variable

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

On my web site, I need to perform a wild card query with a value provided by the end user.  The best practice is to use a PreparedStatement mainly to avoid SQL Injection.  My query is very very long so this is an example:

```
String query = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ..."+ //
"AND UPPER(CUST_NAME) LIKE UPPER('%?%')";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, "joe");
```

The problem is the setString() throws an exception:  SQL Exception: Invalid column index

Comment: Found the answer: Replace 'UPPER('%?%')' with this 'UPPER(CONCAT(CONCAT('%',?),'%'))'    Does anyone have any other or better suggestion?

Comment: `UPPER(CONCAT('%',?,'%'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the concat operator you could use

```
like upper('%' || ? || '%')
```

slightly more readable.

Comment: MS SQL:
like upper('%' + ? + '%')

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
String query = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ..."+ //
"AND UPPER(CUST_NAME) LIKE UPPER(?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, "%joe%");
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace...

```
UPPER('%?%')
```

...with...

```
UPPER(?)
```

...then set the parameter value as:

```
pstmt.setString(1, "%joe%");
```

BTW this query has a potential for poor performance. For good performance you'll need a functional index on `UPPER(CUST_NAME)` ("normal" index on `CUST_NAME` is not enough) **and** you'll need to only query by prefix (e.g. "joe%"). Querying by suffix (such as "%joe" or "%joe%") cannot be sped-up by an index.